# how to generate unit test code for methods

Tags: python, unit-testing

i want to write code for unit test to test my application code. I have different methods and now want to test these methods one by one in python script.
but i do not how to i write. can any one give me example of small code for unit testing in python.
i am thankful

Answer (score 7):

Read the [unit testing framework section](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-unittest.html) of the [Python Library Reference](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/lib.html).

A [basic example](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/minimal-example.html) from the documentation:

```
import random
import unittest

class TestSequenceFunctions(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.seq = range(10)

    def testshuffle(self):
        # make sure the shuffled sequence does not lose any elements
        random.shuffle(self.seq)
        self.seq.sort()
        self.assertEqual(self.seq, range(10))

    def testchoice(self):
        element = random.choice(self.seq)
        self.assert_(element in self.seq)

    def testsample(self):
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, random.sample, self.seq, 20)
        for element in random.sample(self.seq, 5):
            self.assert_(element in self.seq)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4):

It's probably best to start off with the given `unittest` example. Some standard best practices:

- put all your tests in a `tests` folder at the root of your project.
- write one test module for each python module you're testing.
- test modules should start with the word `test`.
- test methods should start with the word `test`.

When you've become comfortable with `unittest` (and it shouldn't take long), there are some nice extensions to it that will make life easier as your tests grow in number and scope:

- [nose](http://somethingaboutorange.com/mrl/projects/nose/) -- easily find and run all your tests, and more.
- [testoob](http://testoob.sourceforge.net/) -- colorized output (and more, but that's why I use it).
- [pythoscope](http://pythoscope.org/) -- haven't tried it, but this will automatically generate (failing) test stubs for your application. Should save a lot of time writing boilerplate code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [example](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/minimal-example.html) and you might want to read a little more on [pythons unit testing](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-unittest.html).